# Problemas para deserealização do POJO com Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest

Olá, estou treinando com `Rest Assured`, não tenho como mostrar o projeto em si, mas basicamente, é passado `token` e alguns parâmetros por header,  e a API retorna vários dados, seria algo como :

```
{
   "data": {
         "data_nascimento" : "exemplo",
         "nome_completo" : "exemplo",
         "numero_cpf" : "exemplo",
         "vivo" : true
    }
}
```

A classe eu criei da seguinte forma:

```
public Class Data {

 private String data_nascimento;
 private String nome_completo;
 private String numero_cpf;
 private boolean vivo;

 //Getter e Setter
```

}

E na chamada estou tentando de duas formas diferentes, mas ambas retornam valor null

```
Data dados = given()
               .header(//map com header e token)
             when.
               .get("/cliente").as(Data.class);
```

Essa foi uma das formas a outra foi usar `extract().body().as(Data.class)`, porém os dados não estão sendo deserializados.

Comment: Consegui resolver, criei uma classe separada e chamei essa classe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo a seguinte chamada:

```
 public class DadosPessoa{

@JsonProperty("data_nascimento")
private String data_nascimento;

@JsonProperty("nome_completo")
 private String nome_completo;

@JsonProperty("numero_cpf")
 private String numero_cpf;

@JsonProperty("vivo")
 private boolean vivo; 

//getter e setter
```

E em outra classe eu chamei ela da seguinte forma:

```
public class Data{

@JsonProperty("data")
private DadosPessoa dados;

public DadosPessoa getDados(){
return dados;
}

//toString
```

a partir dai quando faço a chamado só pegar o "getDados().getNome_completo();" por exemplo

Tive que ler alguns posts para entender onde estava errando, mas deu certo aqui.